# How to send std::list<std::string> in JNI C to Android

Tags: java, android, c, list, java-native-interface

**sample.cc:**

```
 std::list<std::string> lst;
 lst.push_back("this");
 lst.push_back("is");
 lst.push_back("test");
 lst.push_back("message");
```

**java_c_reference.cc:**

```
CALLBACK_START("handleSampleData",**XXXX**, objectReference);
if(mid != NULL){
env->CallVoidMethod(reference_->handler_object, mid, **YYYY**);
}
DETACH_FROM_VM(reference_);
```

Here XXXX is **signature** and YYYY is **JNI datatype** 
   How to use a Signature and JNI type for `std::list<std::string> lst` to obtain my  lst in Java `ArryList<String>`

**Test.java:**

```
public void handleSampleData(ArrayList<String> arrSample){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer, Iteratively copy it to an ArrayList you construct in JNI and then pass that new object back to the JVM.

```
jclass ArrayList_class = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/util/ArrayList");
ArrayList_init_id = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, ArrayList_class, "<init>", "()V");
ArrayList_add_id = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, ArrayList_class, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z");
jobject List_obj = (*env)->NewObject(env, ArrayList_class, ArrayList_init_id);

// Begin psudo-code
foreach (item in lst) {
    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, List_obj, ArrayList_add_id, (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, item));
}

// Now pass List_obj to where ever it needs to go.

// I usually call DeleteLocalRef to make sure the objects get garbage collected.
(*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, List_obj);
```

Comment: it shows an error as java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='add' signature='(Ljava/lang/Object;)V' in class Ljava/util/ArrayList;

Comment: The 'z' should be a capital 'Z'.  Fixed above ;)

Comment: NewStringUTF creates a Java string (which has the Unicode/UTF-16 character set and encoding) from a C string that has the _modified_ UTF-8 character set and encoding. @No_Rulz, what is the character set and encoding used in `lst`. On Android it's probably _standard_ UTF-8.  If you know you can use the `String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). Otherwise you can use the `String(byte[] byte)` constructor, which takes uses the JVM's default encoding for the platform.

Comment: @AlexBarker ya I already gave a capital Z.. and I think my problem is not based on NewStringUTF because the compiler is not compile after ArrayList_add_id = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, ArrayList_class, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z"); line.. :(